# Autofill a form of another website and send it

Tags: php, forms, curl, autofill

I searched the web and found nothing.

On the website, there is a Input box for a E-Mail address. I would like to fill this field with an e-mail address and the send the form. Then i will get the whole source code from the website.

I **don't** wanna give this to the URL like "?myvar=test&myvar2=test2". I searched for examples for CURL, but found nothing.

I only want fill the form, send it, and get the source code. Or is there an addon for firefox or a free program?

With best regards
KalTo

Comment: You talk about sending a form, and getting some source code. Source code to what? The response? You then talk about using cURL (presumably from PHP based on the tags), then mention Firefox and free programs. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: He's terribly confused. KalTo: learn about HTTP, how to create HTTP requests manually, with telnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to look at the form action attribute. This should point you to the script the form is posted to. When you have that information you can send a POST request to that url using curl or when in php,

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'email' => 'youremailaddress'
    )
); 
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but not the way you expect. To `POST` a form, you need to first fetch the source code for it (with Curl, or whatever your preference). For each `input` on the form, you store the `name` and give it a value. Then you need to send those values with their respective names to the `action` url of the `form`, using the `method` and `enctype`  specified on the form.