# Send username to external webpage form using PHP

Tags: php, external, html, autofill

I am logged into my website. From there I need to go to an external website and log in again with the same username/password.  Instead of having to type in username/password again I want it to happen automatically. In the same way a browsers autofill does it when you visit a page you have been to before except I want to do it server side.  I would like to do it in php.

This is the relevant section of the external webpage:

```
<div id="loginbox">
 <h3 id="login">Login</h3>
  <form action="" method="post" name="">
   <table class="login" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td width="190" class="left">Username</td>
       <td width="695"><input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="30"></td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="left">Password</td>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="30"></td>

    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I get you right but you can't access the client's browser with PHP. This is JS/Ajax.

Comment: so user logs in on a page and you redirect to external page, then on external page you have another check for username and password but instead of user re-entering it you want to autopopulate it?

Comment: Do you have access on that extarnal page ?

Comment: The external webpage is a public webpage with a login form.  I posted the login form above. I am already logged in on my website with the same username/password that this external public webpage also requires.  Instead of having to type it in my username/password again I want the form to autofill.  Again, exactly like what happens when you go to a website you have been to before and your browser autofills in username/password.  All you need to do is click the login button.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot do much (and thank god for that because our internet would be so incredibly much less secure if you could).

Comment: I know you can do it.  There are scripts all over the place for doing it.  I just can't quite get it to work.  There are no security issues.  They already need to be logged in on my website in order for this to work on the other website.  If someone were to break in and get that log in information it wouldn't matter either way.

Comment: You are not talking about OAuth, are you ? If there are so many scripts doing it, why don't you point us to some ?

Comment: Server side you can do it with cURL and maybe GET/POST.  Client side you can do it with Java which is an option if it's simpler but I would prefer using PHP.  You can google it

Comment: This post is kind of what I am looking for.  Only the first half.  They want to collect the data which I am not doing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787872/autofill-a-form-of-another-website-and-send-it

Answer (score 0):

A good option is create a **RESTful Service API** in PHP and your webform could comunicate with API to login and mutch more.

Some interesting tutorials:

- (with download) http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/create-restful-services-api-in-php.html
- http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/
- (beginner info) http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest/

Comment: Had not considered that.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Was kind of hoping for a recipe but maybe the google gods will oblige.