# Fill login form from another page

Tags: html, forms, post, authentication

I'm a HTML newbie and I'm completing a website where I'd put the login form to another website.

Basically I'd like to have two forms, one for the user and one for the password, of course, and a "fake" login buttom. Basically it'll switch to the real login page, fill the proper forms doing the real login.

Is it possible? Using Chrome I saw that the login page is something like this:

```
<form action="websitepath/home.xhtml" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="xwt.act" value="DO_LOGIN">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" class="m2">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td align="center" class="gray">
                Username:
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="text" size="15" id="username" name="xwt.usr">
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="center" class="gray">
                Password:
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="password" size="15" id="password" name="xwt.pwd">
            </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to send the input directly into another form, but it should be possible (depending how the 2nd site handles login) to send the form directly from you to the original login form's action page.

Your form would should send the same inputs as the original form, and have the same action (websitepath/home.xhtml), with the full URL for the action.

Also - [Autofill a form of another website and send it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787872/autofill-a-form-of-another-website-and-send-it)

Answer (score 0):

You can post a form to another page quite easily with html+php

The basic gist of it is as follows:

Your Form On Site A

set the action to the target page and name your fields something logical

Site B

```
<?php

$variableOne = $_GET['fieldname'];
$variableTwo = $_GET['otherfieldname'];

?>
```

This is where it gets a little fuzzy on your intentions, you don't actually have to display another login page here, you can actually just push those values to your login script but if you absolutely want redundant login forms you can recreate the form on Site B and assign the field values to :

and it will grab the posted data for you again then you can drive your login form to whatever you normally do.

Hope this Helps

Comment: ok .. ! I'm really a newbie so please guide me a little bit! I have access to my page html and I can modify it of course, but I can't edit anything to the other site. How should I menage these php stuffs ... !?

Comment: remote url? Can you explain me? :)

Comment: the remote url being the url of the site you want to login to

for example.

<form method="POST" action="[http://www.google.com/websitepath/home.xhtml](http://www.google.com/websitepath/home.xhtml)">

Comment: yes, it's the same. except I would say its unlikely you need to include a port in the url, unless it operates on something other than port 80. He's also correct in saying you could post the form in ajax though I don't see that as being a valuable solution for you as you intend to leave your page anyways. The only reason I would use that is for form validation.

Comment: the port is not the 80 one

Answer (score 0):

if you can't modify the other site then my above method wont work for you. Your only option would be to be create a form on Site A as follows

```
<form method="POST" action="http://remoteurl/websitepath/home.xhtml">
    <input type="hidden" name="xwt.act" value="DO_LOGIN">
    <input type="text" name="xwt.usr">
    <input type="password" name="xwt.pwd">
</form>
```

This would in theory direct your login to the login script on the remote site.